# Spring MVC приложение при конфигурации через Java файл выдает ошибку 404. Среда разработки Eclipse

Tags: java, spring-mvc

При попытке запроса по данным URL http://localhost:8080/hello и http://localhost:8080/goodbye выдает ошибку 404.

Структура проекта:

[image: структура проекта]

Config Java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "ru.fedormakarov.springcourse")
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

```
package ru.fedormakarov.springcourse.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{ SpringConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{ "/" };
    }

}
```

Контроллер:

```
package ru.fedormakarov.springcourse.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class FirstController {
    
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String helloPage() {
        return "first/hello";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/goodbye")
    public String goodByePage() {
        return "first/goodbye";
    }
}
```

Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ru.fedormakarov.springcourse</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring_mvc_app1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>spring_mvc_app1 Maven Webapp</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring.version>5.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Описание ошибки 404:
The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exist

Comment: Вставьте, пожалуйста, код в виде текста. Так на Ваш вопрос гораздо быстрее найдется ответ.

Comment: Также на всякий случай приложите содержимое `pom.xml`, чтобы было понятно с какой версией спринга вы работаете и какой шаблонизатор используете.

Comment: Все исправил! спасибо за совет

Comment: спасибо за понимание. Постараюсь сам ответить если время найду

Comment: можно один уточняющий вопрос? Вы пытались создать приложение без `web.xml`?

Comment: У меня к сожалению сегодня не так много времени, и если и отвечу, то скорее всего либо ночью сегодня либо уже завтра.

Comment: да создаю на основе java config

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57550229/new-project-using-spring-mvc-5-in-eclipse-but-i-am-having-error-404

нашел ответ, надо было добавить maven зависимости через deployment assembly